# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel: Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: “module.scibert_layer.embeddings.position_ids”

Tags: pytorch, state-dict

I am getting the following error while trying to load a saved model checkpoint (`.pth` file).

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel: Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "module.scibert_layer.embeddings.position_ids"
```

I trained my sequence labeling model in `nn.DataParallel` (torch version `1.7.0`) but am trying to load it without the `nn.DataParallel` (torch version `1.9.0`). Currently, I understand that not using `nn.DataParallel` caused the issue of `RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel:`, but could it also be because I am using different versions of torch or training and loading the model checkpoint?

The model is wrapped in `nn.DataParallel` using the following chunk of code.

```
    if exp_args.parallel == 'true':
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [0, 1, 2, 3])
            print("Using", len(model.device_ids), " GPUs!")
            print("Using", str(model.device_ids), " GPUs!")
        model.to(f'cuda:{model.device_ids[0]}')
    elif exp_args.parallel == 'false':
        model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [0])
```

This is my model.

```
DataParallel(
  (module): SCIBERTPOSAttenCRF(
    (scibert_layer): BertModel(
      (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
        (word_embeddings): Embedding(31090, 768, padding_idx=0)
        (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
        (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
        (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      )
      (encoder): BertEncoder(
        (layer): ModuleList(
          (0): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (1): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (2): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (3): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (4): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (5): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (6): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (7): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (8): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (9): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (10): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (11): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
        )
      )
      (pooler): BertPooler(
        (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
        (activation): Tanh()
      )
    )
    (lstmpos_layer): LSTM(44, 20, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
    (self_attention): MultiheadAttention(
      (out_proj): NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear(in_features=40, out_features=40, bias=True)
    )
    (lstm_layer): LSTM(808, 512, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
    (hidden2tag): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=2, bias=True)
    (crf_layer): CRF(num_tags=2)
  )
)
```

How should I go ahead with correctly wrapping the checkpoint in `nn.DataParallel` or should I use the correct version of the torch that could fix this problem?

I will be grateful for any help or hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not caused by the `DataParallel` library, but rather the `transformers` library (notice that I used the `SciBERT` model from huggingface `transformers` library).
The error was caused by using older versions of `transformers` and `tokeniezrs`. Upgrading the `transformers` version from `3.0.2` to `4.8.2` and `tokeniezrs` to `0.10.3`

Answer (score 2):

**Change:**

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path + '/pytorch_model.pt'))
```

**to**

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path + '/pytorch_model.pt'), strict=False)
```